# Help identify details from a Soviet military uniform?

Tags: military, soviet-union, identification, uniform

My family on my great-grandfather's side came from Romania and I have a picture of one of his brothers in a soviet military uniform.

I know nothing of his involvement in the military and was hoping by posting a picture of him in his uniform, someone could discern some meaning from it such as what branch he was a part of or his rank. This ancestor was born about 1899 if that helps. I don't know exactly when the photo was taken.

[image: man in military uniform]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The rank is "младший сержант" (the dictionary gives me "lance-sergeant" but one should be careful here - I'm not good at British or American ranks).

Comment: At least it's a starting point. Thanks!

Comment: I could give a bit more, actually, but I'm having a problem with the English equivalents here :) (A weird feeling, as I'm more or less fluent in English but all these Soviet/Russian military terms - not a clue how to present them). For example, "младший сержант" is denoted by the two stripes on his "погоны" (the "thingies on his shoulders" - what the hell is the English term for them - epaulets? shoulder boards?)   Later on I might try to make an answer out of this. Not tonight, though.

Comment: The branch of the military would be shown on "pogony" (shopulder boards?) as a little sign between the button and the stripes. Perhaps if you magnify the photo very much it will be possible to see what is this. And also the sign on the right of his chest. The sign on the left side has the shape of the Komsomol member sign but again it is not clearly visible. (I refer to the "left" and "right" with respect to the person standing in the photo. His shirt is a generic Soviet army shirt before and including WWII period, but even in 1970s some soldiers were wearing this style of shirt.

Comment: The trousers are unusual: why they are black? Normally they will be of the same color as the shirt (khaki). I wore this exact kind of uniform in the 1970s, except the black trousers but at that time it was very much out of date.

Comment: Right, the dates given in the question (`born about 1899 and looks to be in his thirties`) do not seem right. At first this was intuitive - the man just somehow 'does not look' like someone from the 30s... Then I realised what's odd and double-checked - the 'pogony' (погоны) were only introduced in 1943. To @Alex - yes, it's definitely a 'комсомольский значок' on the left side and most probably [значок "Отличник Советской Армии"](https://images.app.goo.gl/DcBctsMyMbmquQf88) on the right side (not 100%, there were a few of them very similar in shape).

Comment: … and if it's indeed "Отличник Советской Армии" - the photo is dated no earlier than 1957 because the badge did not exist before then ("учрежден приказом Министра обороны Советского Союза от 17.04.1957").

Comment: I will post close-ups of the suggested areas. Thank you so much for the information! I am surprised though that the uniform is from so late. As I said, I have no idea when it was taken.

Comment: @tum_: Wikipedia translates "*младший сержант*" as *Junior Sergeant*, and would likely be equivalent to *Corporal* in the U.S. Army of the same time period.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Yeah, that's probably correct. I simply don't know US/BR military ranks and, as each country has their own system, in general, one wouldn't expect a one to one match... Anyway, *младший сержант* is the third rank from the bottom in the Soviet as well as the modern Russian army.

Comment: @Cerulean Oh, and by the way - he is most probably in his early twenties. Komsomol was a youth organisation, one would typically become a *komsomolets* at the age of 14-15 and the upper age  bound of remaining a member was 29 if I remember correctly. Some would leave earlier by becoming a member of the Communist Party. Again - this is if the badge on his left (heart) side is indeed a badge of a komsomolets.  A close-up would be helpful.

Comment: @tum_: Both the USSR and the US had seven enlisted rank levels below Warrant officer at the time.

Comment: The birth date is right. It is probably my age estimation that is off. I just posted the closeup, but the details on the shoulder pads are still hard to make out even when I zoom in.

Comment: @Cerulean well, there are obviously other guys on the photo - their insignia might look more readable. It is logical to assume that all of them are from the same "division".

Comment: I gave your question another careful read - when you say "this ancestor..." are you talking about the man on the photo or his brother, your great-grandfather? In any case, though, the dates simply don't tally with the historical evidence, I'm sorry. The man on the photo was born around 1930 at the earliest (most probably - later). Thus, he could hardly be a brother of someone born in 1899. A nephew, maybe?

Comment: The other people in the photo are his brother and sister. That is supposed to be my great-grandfather's brother. His name is on the back of the photo. But admittedly, he does look far younger than his siblings. I thought it could just be good genes, but given how names are reused in families, this man could be a nephew with the brother's name. Sorry about the confusion this is causing.

Comment: It is still not clear what the little sign between the strips and the button on the shoulder stip is. These signs denote the branch of service, and they are shown in this Wikipedia page: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0_1943%E2%80%941955

Comment: These closeups are the best I can do. The picture still isn't very clear, but luckily, most of the branch signs use crossed axes or shovels or are cross shaped. These appears to be neither which will help narrow it down. I'm leaning towards the badge that is shaped like a shield.